# call on function when all images are clicken on

Tags: javascript, html, window, image

I want to call a function that opens a new link. I want to do this after all my images have been clicked on. How can i achieve this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1252"> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">   </script>
        <![endif]--> 
    <title>Date med mig - version b
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function newWindow()
    {
        window.location = window.location = "http://www.tv3.se/datemedmig"
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Del 2: Date med mig</h1>    

    <img src="1_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="this.src='1_o.jpg';" alt="image" />
    <img src="2_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="this.src='2_o.jpg';" alt="image" />
    <img src="3_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="this.src='3_o.jpg';" alt="image" />
    <img src="4_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="this.src='4_o.jpg';" alt="image" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question, in its current form, is too broad to get many useful responses on Stack Overflow.

Comment: im actually clueless on where and how to call my function newWindow(), so that it gets called after every image has been clicked on.

Comment: btw, having same ID for multiple elements are bad idea and asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to just load a new window as soon as any image is clicked, I think the way that @runfaj said to do it is probably the best, It is my understanding that you want to do it only after ALL images have been clicked on?

If this is the case, here's one option (which is probably not the most efficient)

```
//Assuming there are 4 images
var hasBeenClicked = [false,false,false,false]

//To be called when each image is clicked
function imageClicked(whichImage){ 

    this.src = "'"+whichImage+"_o.jpg'"

    //set this position in the array equal to true
    hasBeenClicked[whichImage] = true

    // if the array is completely true (every image has been clicked)
    // call the newWindow function
    if(hasBeenClicked == [true,true,true,true]){
          newWindow();
    }

}
```

Then when you create an image:

```
<img src="1_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="imageClicked(1);" alt="image" />
```

Comment: <img src="1_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="imageClicked(this.src='1_o.jpg');" alt="image" />, this is how i call the function, but it will not work ?

Comment: im I calling the function correctly ? 
<img src="1_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="imageClicked(this.src='1_o.jpg');" alt="image" />

Comment: i cant make it to work. i call it this way:
<img src="1_c.jpg" id="image1" onclick="imageClicked(this.src='1_o.jpg');" alt="image" />, but nothing happens, and i do this in every img

Comment: if(hasBeenClicked == [true,true,true,true]){ , this line does not execute. i tried by putting an alert inside it, and it never reached it.

Comment: try it now. but basically what you need to do is make the source change part of another function that does everything you want, so you are only calling one function, in the onclick, but within that function you can do multiple things.

Comment: i did try your way, but the new image does not get shown. i put this.src in an alert, and when i click on the first img, i get the correct name, 1_o.jpg, however the img never changes

Comment: Interesting... I honestly have no idea on that one :(

Answer (score 0):

you could do it three ways:

jquery:

```
$('img').click(newWindow);
```

inline:

```
<img src=..... onclick="newWindow()" />
```

regular javascript:

get all the tags with:

```
var imgs = document.getElementByTagName('img');
```

then add an event listener to each one (google it for lots of different examples)

Answer (score 0):

Have an onclick function that triggers for each image which sets a new attribute on the image tag. Then run a loop over all images to check that they all have the tag. If so, open new windows. For example:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).data('was-clicked', true);

     var all_clicked = true;
     $('img').each(function() {
         if($(this).data('was-clicked') != true) {
             all_clicked = false;
             break;
         }
     });

     if(all_clicked == true) newWindow();
 });
```

Note, this code is not tested and may have syntax/semantic errors. Also, you may not really want the user to click ALL image tags (e.g. banners, backgrounds, etc), so you should modify the jquery selectors to filter only the 'img' tags you're interested in, e.g. $('#my-gallery img')...

Comment: thank you, but the solution is supposed to be in pure javascript, no jQuery.